# How to standardize date format by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

There is column A and B with different date format :

- 20200714
- 44043
- 2020/09/01
- 2021/1/4

is there any VBA to standardize the date format as the same format?

- 2020/7/14
- 2020/7/31
- 2020/9/1
- 2021/1/4

  ```
   Sub text()
    Dim lastRow, l As Long
    lastRow = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For l = 2 To lastRow
    Range("A" & l).Select
    Selection.NumberFormatLocal = "yyyy/m/d"
    Next
  End Sub
  ```

after run code, some cell show as `####`, some looks good as `yyyy/m/d`.

Comment: Are those cells entered as text or as a formatted date value?

Comment: updated code as above, thank you

Comment: Those not "looking good" are probably just text. These you must edit manually.

Comment: If they do not change using the `.NumberFormat` that means they are text and not dates. Those can not reliably converted into dates because Excel does not know which format those strings are. The only reliable way then is to split that string into parts and use `DateSerial(Year, Month, Day)` to generate a numeric date and format it with `.NumberFormat` to your desired format.

Comment: I highly recommend only to use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standardized formatted dates when using strings. This is the only date format that can reliably converted into a numeric date and cannot be [misunderstood](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function DateConv(strVal) As Date
   If IsDate(strVal) Then
        DateConv = strVal
   ElseIf IsNumeric(strVal) And Len(strVal) = 5 Then
        DateConv = CDate(CLng(strVal))
   ElseIf IsNumeric(strVal) And Len(strVal) = 8 Then
        DateConv = DateSerial(CLng(left(strVal, 4)), CLng(Mid(strVal, 5, 2)), CLng(Right(strVal, 2)))
    ElseIf Len(strVal) = 8 Then
       Dim arrD: arrD = Split(strVal, "/")
       DateConv = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(0)), CLng(arrD(1)), CLng(arrD(2)))
   End If
End Function
```

It can be used to convert a column (A:A as example) in the next way:

```
Sub makeDate()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrD, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   lastR = Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value
   ReDim arrD(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arrD(i, 1) = DateConv(arr(i, 1))
   Next i
   
   With sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrD), 1)
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
        .value = arrD
    End With
End Sub
```

Of course, the range to be converted **must exist in column "A:A"**...

There may be problems only if the format date (brought from somewhere...) does not have a similar format. I mean "yyyy/dd/mm" instead of "yyyy/mm/yy".

Comment: I think this `ElseIf Len(strVal) = 5 Then` is not needed if there is a number that represents a date then `.NumberFormat` will correct it. No need to convert it then.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Probably, yes. But, usually Excel convert (and show it as date if a `Long` number in the recognized `Date` range). That's why I thought that it will be safer to firstly convert it as a 'Long', then, even if not strictly necessarily convert it to `Date`. But, yes, the `CDate` part may be missing... In fact, I will eliminate it from the code. Did it. Thanks!

Comment: I still recommed to check if the 5 digit value `IsNumeric` as well as the 8 digit value needs do be numeric. If it really comes accross an 5 or 8 digit value that contains text it will throw an exception. Like `2021/1/4` is 8 digits if this is text, this will throw an exception. Probably RegEx is a more secure way here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, I missed the last example. I copied the range on my computer to make some tests and it correctly converted both cases of dates... You are right. for such a case the string should be split and use `DateSerial` on the resulted elements...